# number of strings between .txt files

Tags: python, string, text, numbers

I am new in Python. I am looking for the number of occurrences of a text string in a defined folder containing text files. I'm talking about the total number of this particular string.

```
def errors():
    
    errors = 0
    file = open ("\\d:\\myfolder\\*.txt", "r")
    data = file.read()
    errors = data.count("errors")
    return errors
    print("Errors:", errors)
```

Comment: Please show your efforts. SO isn't a work-offloading system.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm attaching my existing code above.

Comment: Why is there a \ at the start of your path? You can't just open any number of files with a single `open` command and expect `.read()` to sort it out - you'll need to open the files one at a time and process the contents, adding up the total count.

Comment: Something you might find helpful is `os.listdir()`, which returns a list of all the entries in a path and `file.readlines()`, which returns a list of all the lines in a text file.

Comment: @FrantisekSchimanski - if my answer helped please upvote/accept. If not please explain why not. This is another common practice of SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make any sense, but if I understand what you want to do, then here's some pseudo-code to get you going:

```
from glob import glob

text_file_paths = glob("\\d:\\myfolder\\*.txt") 
error_counting = 0
for file_path in text_file_paths:
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        all_file_lines = f.readlines()
    error_counting += sum([line.count('errors') for line in all_lines])

print(error_counting)
```

Does that help?